# Change styling of If Statements in Emacs?

Tags: regex, emacs

My company has recently added some new code styling rules, and I would was wondering if there is an easy way via emacs to change a couple things w/ a regex replace.

if statements now have to look like the following:

```
if (expression) {
```

where I have many that look like so:

```
if(expression){
```

lacking the spaces. Is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: Depending on how much you need to clean up, you might try astyle (http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html) or another formatting tool, which is specifically designed to standardize formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to regexp replace it if `expression` is always on one line, but I'd use a throw-away function just to be safe:

```
(defun my-fix-style ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (re-search-forward "\\_<if(" nil t)
      (backward-char)
      (insert " ")
      (forward-sexp)
      (unless (looking-at "[ \t\n]")
        (insert " ")))))
```

Comment: It's not foolproof but it''ll work mostly. You might also consider just using `query-replace-regexp`.

Comment: Yes, it depends on what kind of code has been written.  Consider: `if(something_is_true()){ something_else(); }`  (That's supposed to be on a single line)  Since regexps can't count the parens, how do you get that one right?  Granted it's pathological, but that's why I'd use a function.

Answer (score 1):

Just my two cents, but if I was going to do this with emacs, I'd probably avoid regular expressions and approach it in two parts.  First I'd do the search to  replace `if(` with `if (` by doing a Meta-% "if("  "if ("  The quote marks are just for delineation, they don't belong in the entered text.  Then either answer each individual replacement query, or give it a "!" to tell it to do all replacements.  Repeat the process for the closing `){` to `) {`.

Off the top of my head, I'd expect the first substituion to work without issue.  The second one will also get "){" combinations in loops, but if your new standard demands a space for if statements, I'd expect it to do so for loops as well, so that seems like it should be a good thing.